# Database design: how to represent a field which can be of several types?

Tags: database, database-design

In my database model I want to represent a table PROPERTY which, among other fields, should have a field called "value". This value should be able to contain any type: integer, decimal, text, date, etc.
What is the best approach to achieve this? Having one field for each type (valueInteger, valueDate, etc) and filling only the desired one -> lots of empty fields? Or maybe store only string field which then should be parsed to the correct type?

Besides PROPERTY table, I will also need a PROPERTY_RANGE table, which will contain a lowerValue and upperValue fields. If I chose to have a field for each type, in this table I will need 2 fields (lower, upper) for each supported type.

I can also think about using some sort of tablet inheritance to distinguish "value" field type (although this may be killing a fly with a shotgun).

What is the best approach to solve this question?

Comment: this is called EAV and it is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I would go with a table that contains one column per each possible data type of the property, both for correctness and maintainability. This will help especially during querying the records where the filters on different data types are different and converging all values to a VARCHAR field means that we need to convert these values to appropriate type at runtime which could prove costly, depending on the size of the table.